# jQuery search only searching the page its on

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have laravel data which is paginated using laravels default paginator like so.

Controller

```php
$applications = Application::onlyTrashed()->latest()->paginate(25);
return view('index', compact('applications'));
```

The table is my blade template is like this

```php
<label for="kwd_search">Search:</label> <input type="text" id="kwd_search" value=""/>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="my-table1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th>{{ trans('crud.users.id') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('Name') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('Email') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('Country') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('Contact No') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('counsellor') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('Submitted On') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('Status') }}</th>
            <th>{{ trans('crud.actions') }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($archivedApplications as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! $row->id !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $row->name ?: 'No Name Provided'!!}</td>
            <td>{!! $row->email !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $row->country['name'] ?: 'No Country Provided' !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $row->contact_no ?: 'No Number Provided' !!}</td>
            <td>{!! ((isset($row->counsellor->name))?$row->counsellor->name:'') !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $row->created_at !!}</td>

            <!-- additional td -->
            <td>
                <span class="blockify-button btn-warning">{!! trans('Archived') !!}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The below is my JS for searching. It currently only searches the current page, not just the one I'm on.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
    $("#kwd_search").keyup(function(){
        // When value of the input is not blank
        var term=$(this).val()
        if( term != "")
        {
            // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
            $("#my-table1 tbody>tr").hide();
            $("#my-table1 td").filter(function(){
                   return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term ) >-1
            }).parent("tr").show();
        }
        else
        {
            // When there is no input or clean again, show everything back
            $("#my-table1 tbody>tr").show();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what difference is between "current" page and "the one I'm on", but if you want to filter not only rendered table but whole database , you should send ajax request with `#kwd_search` content, make sql request with it and recieve result list.
Probably better solution is to get whole list from DB trough ajax on page load split it and render table with js framework. In this case you can operate with whole data without unnecessary ajax requests.